# Discount reward in REINFORCE deep reinforcement learning algorithm

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, reward

I'm implementing a REINFORCE with baseline algorithm, but I have a doubt with the **discount reward function**.

I implemented the discount reward function like this:

```
  def disc_r(rewards):
        r = np.zeros_like(rewards)
        tsteps = range(len(rewards)) #timesteps
        sum_reward = 0
        for i in reversed(tsteps):
            sum_reward = rewards[i] + gamma*sum_reward
            r[i] = sum_reward
            print(r[i])
        return r - np.mean(r)
```

Therefore, for example, for a discount factor `gamma = 0.1` and a reward `rewards = [1,2,3,4]` it gives:

`r = [1.234, 2.34, 3.4, 4.0]`

which is correct according to the expression of the return *G*:

> The return is the sum of discounted rewards: G = discount_ factor * G + reward

However, and here my question, I found this article from Towards Data Science https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-reinforcement-learning-reinforce-with-pytorch-5e8ad7fc7da0 where they define this same function as follows:

```
def discount_rewards(rewards, gamma=0.99):
    r = np.array([gamma**i * rewards[i] for i in range(len(rewards))])
    # Reverse the array direction for cumsum and then revert back to the original order
    r = r[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
    print(r)
    return r — r.mean()
```

Computing for the same `gamma = 0.1` and a reward `rewards = [1,2,3,4]` it gives:

`r = [1.234, 0.234, 0.034, 0.004]`

But I don't see the process here, it seems it doesn't follow the rule of *G*...

Does someone know what is going on with this second function and why it could also be correct (or in which cases maybe...)?

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that the second function is incorrect. A corrected version of this, that uses numpy and is more efficient than your first function would be:

```
def discount_rewards(rewards, gamma):
    t_steps = np.arange(rewards.size)
    r = rewards * gamma**t_steps
    r = r[::-1].cumsum()[::-1] / gamma**t_steps
    return r
```

Also, it seems to me that your first function is also incorrect. Why are you subtracting the mean on the return statement? And be careful to initialize `r = np.zeros_like(rewards, dtype=float)` otherwise numpy might treat it as an integer vector and floor the results.